# Downloading a large file in PHP, max 8192 bytes?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the following code to download a large file (>100mb). The code is executed in a shell.

```
$fileHandle = fopen($url, 'rb');
$bytes = 100000;

while ($read = @fread($fileHandle, $bytes)) {
    debug(strlen($read));

    if (!file_put_contents($filePath, $read, FILE_APPEND)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Where I would expect that `debug(strlen($read))` would output `100000`, this is the actual output:

```
10627
8192
8192
8192
...
```

Why doesn't `fread` read more than `8192` bytes after the first time, and why does it read `10627` bytes on the first iteration?

This makes downloading the file very slow, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Quoting from the PHP docs: `if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file, at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size`

Comment: But why not simply use [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)? if you're just sending a file to the browser for download, fast and almost no memory overhead

Comment: Thanks, @MarkBaker. How can I use `readfile()` to write to a local file? Functions such as `file_get_contents` fail because the maximum memory size is exceeded.

Comment: or use [stream_copy_to_stream()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php)

Comment: or simply `exec(wget....)` and relax

Comment: @MarkBaker `stream_copy_to_stream()` works as a charm! Could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is (quoting from the PHP docs for [fread()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)):

> if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file, at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size (usually 8192) is made; depending on the previously buffered data, the size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size

The solution to your performance problem is to using [stream_copy_to_stream()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php) which should be faster than block reading using `fread()`, and more memory efficient as well

Answer (score 0):

I checked the manual, and found this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php
"If the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file, at most one read of up to a number of bytes equal to the chunk size (usually 8192) is made;"

Since you're opening a URL this is probably the case.
It doesn't explain the 10627 though...

Besides that, why do you expect 100000 byte reads to be faster than 8192?
I doubt that's your bottle neck. My guess is that either the download speed from the URL or the writing speed of the HD is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, downloading the exact same file using a browser results in *much faster* downloading.

Comment: The answer to the 10627 lies in a bit you didn't quote: `depending on the previously buffered data, the size of the returned data may be larger than the chunk size`