# PHP json_encode content-length limit

Tags: php, json, laravel, encoding

I have a web server with CWP (Centos Web Panel) installed on it and PHP 7.4 configured.

There is simple project written in PHP/Laravel to whom I post raw JSON data.

But when I try to post more raw data I saw Laravel application didn't get post data.

For debugging I create a little test.php file with content below:

```php
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r(json_decode($json));
print_r(json_last_error_msg());
```

But saw that when content-length of JSON self is higher than 8192 symbol raw data didn't encoded and function return empty string.

`json_last_error()` return "control character error possibly incorrectly encoded"

When I clear POST data with `preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $json)` there is no content-length limit and I cant post more data

```php
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $json);
print_r(json_decode($json));
print_r(json_last_error_msg());
```

It turns out that all  without clearing raw data when I post JSON data with `8192` character length but if I add one more character the error happened.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading a large file in PHP, max 8192 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185757/downloading-a-large-file-in-php-max-8192-bytes)

Comment: No. Its began to happen in a working server 5-6 ays ago and today I saw it in my another server too. I think it's something with system update. Because I never met such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how but it was an apache web server problem.
After upgrading to apache 2.4.46 version with the same configuration the problem was solved.